# Load bitmap as a content of webview

Tags: android

First I load the bitmap from url and then I want to load this bitmap to webview element.
Is there a way to load bitmap from the app install folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849200/android-how-to-display-a-bitmap-in-a-webview

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to show off the Bitmap, you might want to use an `ImageView`.

Otherwise, I guess the picture is in your `res/drawable` or `assets`-folder:

To show the Image from the `assets`-folder use the following:

```
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourfile.png");
```

Where `browser` is your `WebView`-Object.

---

To show the Image from the `res`-folder, you use something like this:

```
browser.loadUrl("file:///android_res/drawable/yourfile.png");
```