# Display Base64 image in HTML from Android Bitmap

Tags: java, android, html, bitmap, base64

I have tried to display Base64 image on PHP app by convert image from Android app to Base64.It cannot display on my Browser but it is fine in Android app.

My Java Code

```
imgChild.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap bmap = imgChild.getDrawingCache();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

This is Base64 string that got from code above

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAAEsCAYAAAB5fY51AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA
>       ABxpRE9UAAAAAgAAAAAAAACWAAAAKAAAAJYAAACWAAAH8srfvnsAAAe SURBVHgB
>       7NlhkqM2FEXhWUt ZGHZ/x4mIYl6GJD0hNvt9rU/qlKAnp5ww9GZW5Uff/7x10//
>       eQcYwEACAz8SfqTfaDNhAAMbA4QlYUrYGIhhgLDAGgOrlCVlERZhERYGYhggLLDG
>       wCphSViERViEhYEYBggLrDGwSlgSFmERFmFhIIYBwgJrDKwSloRFWIRFWBiIYYCw
>       wBoDq4QlYREWYREWBmIYICywxsAqYUlYhEVYhIWBGAYIC6wxsEpYEhZhERZhYSCG
>       AcICawysEpaERViERVgYiGGAsMAaA6uEJWERFmERFgZiGCAssMbAKmFJWIRFWISF
>       gRgGCAusMbBKWBIWYREWYWEghgHCAmsMrBKWhEVYhEVYGIhhgLDAGgOrhCVhERZh
>       ERYGYhggLLDGwCphSViERViEhYEYBggLrDGwSlgSFmERFmFhIIYBwgJrDKwSloRF
>       WIRFWBiIYYCwwBoDq4QlYREWYREWBmIYICywxsAqYUlYhEVYhIWBGAYIC6wxsEpY
>       EhZhERZhYSCGAcICawysEpaERViERVgYiGGAsMAaA6uEJWERFmERFgZiGCAssMbA
>       KmFJWIRFWISFgRgGCAusMbBKWBIWYREWYWEghgHCAmsMrBKWhEVYhEVYGIhhgLDA
>       GgOrhCVhERZhERYGYhggLLDGwCphSViERViEhYEYBggLrDGwSlgSFmERFmFhIIYB
>       wgJrDKwSloRFWIRFWBiIYYCwwBoDq4QlYREWYREWBmIYICywxsAqYUlYhEVYhIWB
>       GAYIC6wxsEpYEhZhERZhYSCGAcICawysEpaERViERVgYiGGAsMAaA6uEJWERFmER
>       FgZiGCAssMbAKmFJWIRFWISFgRgGCAusMbBKWBIWYREWYWEghgHCAmsMrBKWhEVY
>       hEVYGIhhgLDAGgOrhCVhERZhERYGYhggLLDGwCphSViERViEhYEYBggLrDGwSlgS
>       FmERFmFhIIYBwgJrDKwSloRFWIRFWBiIYYCwwBoDq4QlYREWYREWBmIYICywxsAq
>       YUlYhEVYhIWBGAYIC6wxsEpYEhZhERZhYSCGAcICawysEpaERViERVgYiGGAsMAa
>       A6uEJWERFmERFgZiGCAssMbAKmFJWIRFWISFgRgGCOuFYf154biaXqqlr65nvvS0
>       wgBhEdaHe1aAaXM mgYXbZ4zEd2TAcIirA/lXAHro2lwcWUtc0ltlQHCIqzflLMK
>       zm9NnZvVdcwjqysMEBZhnXSzAtCp6TCwsoY5ZHWVAcIirINqfi79H6NT02HgKojm
>       k9cKA4RFWAfV/HdbwdNt2g1W/eoEdQsDhEVYO838uqxg jWzf1X1qxPWLQwQFmH1
>       jfPP6AyoYdP/hVlvVavW3urVGuqvKUTCIqypH0Ybf9p0g1Cq9Wb10W80/nrSIizC
>       mrlgmGSmTf8UV2VRrXOlvvpM83JFRliEVTqht8Grpl7Pcaxa45b68Rnuc XU 3aE
>       9cbC2oBYOXrgVH29nv1Y1f Z v45rglrOe6D5XthqTZ9 z7VvK3e5rZz1dPm9c5V
>       7z3qveca 14e7/H Jaw3T1gbRCvHEbaq5zh/f1/1tvq p123WnVu853zJbX/hoRF
>       WP mp0oAW30PTjV/P3d/XfW1 r7neN3mVOdjn/t8eREWYS0LaxNE2/S3yqLq2z j
>       Pat3vtc6vbWNPa/YCIuwliW0l0kljNGmr/r2zxitsY2vHLN teeV0uzbEBZhXRJW
>       E0oljB50VU9bu9fbG7v3er1nGHsusREWYX0Ia9ucK8fKvN5GX12719sbu/d6vWcY
>       I6zfNgggvg6IakOP3n3Vt1LvrX1rX2 tbWzlGPUa/zruvvLdSlgS1ukfkBURVHN6
>       0FY9W73XNxq793qj5xh/HrkRFmF1JbEig9mc3iafzW 1Xt9orPXMzqNe488joSvf
>       grAIi7BemIErMkiYS1gvDOsseWy1CtCqf1bvrT2b32q9vtFY65mdR73GJaxyA4Dk
>       sZDMNvJWq75H1T r99aezW 1Xt9orPXMzqNe449l8V7vW8KSsKbimslgVusBOpvf
>       ar2 0VjrmZ1HvcYJawo QB4PyGwjb7XVb1Kt06uP1u7NPY6Nevfjx57e/X6 68fz
>       9xXvXMKSsEpx9WRQjY1grfq2 qh3P36vdfZrun5 qREWYd1NEHuJjDb/fs7setS/
>       ja8eszXUnl9OvW9EWIT1UGF9VjhklSmannxuGSMswloS1hXRbFKZwbgqnc/Mmz1f
>       LVd6hEVYU7kcN/eqRI59x/vVdW6Zd3yW 1xBHb8dYRHWtwhrA/ErjiPg7l9HVtu3
>       JCzCuiSsVdGsiuKe0lp9pnm5EiMswvpWYTV5fEZcbQ3nXBGtfjvCemFhrULwbPNW
>       5PVsv9nveYwsCYuwLicsm/Mxm9N7Pr9nwiIswsJADAOEBdYYWCWOc J4t3dCWIRF
>       WBiIYYCwwBoD67ulCX/vOVESFmERFgZiGCAssMbAKnGcE8e7vRPCIizCwkAMA4QF
>       1hhY3y1N HvPiZKwCIuwMBDDAGGBNQZWieOcON7tnRAWYREWBmIYICywxsD6bmnC
>       33tOlIRFWISFgRgGCAusMbBKHOfE8W7vhLAIi7AwEMMAYYE1BtZ3SxP 3nOiJCzC
>       IiwMxDDwNwAAAP//wDatNAAACdVJREFU7dxRkus2DkDRrGU srDZ/x6SuBK olkE
>       TVF2v0bjuColCQJItXl5he5k5o8///f/v/zjO8AABjIw8EeGh/SMNhMGMPBggLB0
>       mDpsDKRhgLDAmgZWXZYui7AIi7AwkIYBwlrA tcbP7oD3QEG7jNAWISV5u1qw9/f
>       8Nm/Q8IiLMJaMJB9g/ 05yesBaxv/I2QFBbf80/bVH6ez3WChLXYSIT1OfBsat/t
>       CQOERVi6vwUDJ5tKzedkTFgXYd3pugD7OWB9t7W/W8IiLB3WRQZI8/dJk7Auwvqd
>       OqzoWXY31N36cZ5ovCg 1t 9juZ5xO OfaV 9Rz9vStjyv1XkoT1DYTVQxyd98BG
>       OWO8r nPx7zouq ZnUd1J/HZ LuxK/M9xtz57M7d5 2MO8vpx3C 7t4IK5mwZsCv
>       YuMGWOXO7o31/fUs/26sH//V d25VvWv5u7vr8a5cq8f0/lcXISVRFhXwO9zG/h9
>       7Op5G2M8Xh1nN3 cZ3a9O9Zp3mzOMXY69qpunMP1s7gI64cLa7U5du9Fm2a3/iQv
>       mrPFT8a8UtPmiY5XxrqaG80p7v8P6/IfY3fguwrWzpi/Myf6eT75TNGcj/hXfFbz
>       7z7DbIydZ5/Vifmj 2VZ3QF1BdwOxL87Z/b8s2ea5fWxWU0U6 vaeZQ7i7ea8TjL
>       HWNjTX895s6u /zxfJY/xsYa14SVUlgjuCPor65P68e6x3X7zO6tYq3u1XE2xqua
>       dn9W22ItZ3VsueNxVdPujTXjdctbHcca14SVSlgRsCvo 3ufqo/GfRXvny06n40R
>       5fbxWV0f63Oj8z6/P4/yW7zPXZ23/NVxVV/1nj 6J/mj wrQFfTt3ifrV2NH99pz
>       rY5j7Sq3vzfWjdd9bnQ 1rTrKL/FW96rY8tfHV NUfE YRHWas/8undnc/wa5OLJ
>       OOdO Vgzuz4d57Tunc8wG6tSjLAIa2cfbv/6vDXYZtK4EXfKxprZ9ek4O3XvzJk9
>       e/UYYRHW1h5bbZStAQ6Sxjl3hhhrZten4 zUvTNn9uzVY4RFWFt7LNooW8WHSeOc
>       O8OMNbPr03F26t6ZM3v26jHCIqytPTbbKFuFN5LGOXeGGmtm16fj7NS9M2f27NVj
>       hEVYW3ts3ChbRV3SSf07asYxHtc7n9O6nbF3c2bPUD1GWIS1tX/GjbJTNNb01yf1
>       JzX9nO38dJzTujav4/P/kPnk yAswtrZh0//lnCn4BWMJ2Oc1Mye43Sc07rZM4id
>       yYuwCGtnH6YR1uOHeSWDnR94NsZp3WwsMcJ6Ceo7IPkEtHfH/Or6u/M91mHnM1uv
>       07p rDtj3Kntn8E5YRHWYjetNsii7Netvv5XcHHS58/OF6W/bp3WtQHG hbfOY61
>       7Xqn9pHT8k ObY6T2p9e41dCvxK2/bE89hthmfjfzT5/PN pf SMdY/rr/rM5r46
>       fzRGFB9/tiivcpywFsIaAbpzvYJsZ9zvVL/zvI c2TPv1kb1jzG/4jN79ha7On r
>       i47ReFF 5ThhEVa0X57i4yZ5uvmhi3HOdv2h6Z6GbXNFx6fkD11Ec1eOExZhbW23
>       cZNsFd1MGufsr28O/bK8n2t2/nKANyTM5q0eIyzC2tpas42yVXgjaTZnH7sx9MvS
>       fp7V cuBbiSs5q16j7AIa2tLzTbIVuGQ1MYZwtPLlrs6TguDYBsnuP0Ubrk7x6fC
>       N17szF0th7AIa2uLrTbG1gD/JPVj7NT0 a/OV ONtavcdm s2blutXePO3NVzSGs
>       hbCqQnHyc6826cl4n6xZPWu7d3f Ns7O8e5cleoJi7CeOp fDj BnP0X5t FC8Ii
>       rJTCauK5upFa3ep4dUz5XydBwiKs1MLqxbMSR5/36nw1jntfJ6fZd01YhPVjhPVK
>       RDv3Z5tE7PdKqv/ CYuwCKszWb85nH8fUbW1ICzCIqz/hNU2heP3E1VbE8IiLML6
>       R1htQzh X1k91oawCCvlZu1 i7t1SlDfW1Dj hAWYaUUVg/yVWP1tc4JK/0GAHEu
>       iK1XnfXSYemwvGAwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwI
>       i7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYB
>       wgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdV
>       p5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuw
>       CAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcIC
>       axpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX
>       6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7Aw
>       kIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaB
>       VSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWit
>       CYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCG
>       AcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV6
>       64rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AI
>       i7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAs
>       sKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6
>       qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuw
>       MJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCm
>       gTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3O
>       i7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNp
>       GCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqwCIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1
>       UnU6qWitCYuwCAsDaRggLLCmgTV664rX6bwIi7AICwNpGCAssKaBVSdVp5OK1pqw
>       CIuwMJCGAcICaxpYo7eueJ3Oi7AIi7AwkIYBwgJrGlh1UnU6qWit/wYl67h8sCnn
>       egAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==

I have tried to displayed in HTML using

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA....." />
```

How solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems correct , try replacing the BASE64 format to :

```
String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

If it still not works , check out this [answer](http://www.stackoverflow.com/a/15717721)

Hope this helps!